# lighttpd with fastcgi failing to start

Tags: python, fastcgi, lighttpd

I have installed lighttp and python and am trying to run a python project but run into an error with fastcgi when starting the lighttp daemon. This project was running happily on an old server but does not like the new server yet. The config files are the same as the old working server.

```
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (log.c.166) server started
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.1366) --- fastcgi spawning local
    proc: /srv/http/main.py
    port: 0
    socket /tmp/fastcgi.socket
    max-procs: 1
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.1390) --- fastcgi spawning
    port: 0
    socket /tmp/fastcgi.socket
    current: 0 / 1
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.1103) the fastcgi-backend /srv/http/main.py failed to start:
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.1107) child exited with status 1 /srv/http/main.py
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.1110) If you're trying to run your app as a FastCGI backend, make sure you're using the FastCGI-enabled version.
If this is PHP on Gentoo, add 'fastcgi' to the USE flags.
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (mod_fastcgi.c.1398) [ERROR]: spawning fcgi failed.
2015-02-25 07:59:01: (server.c.1021) Configuration of plugins failed. Going down.
```

The relevant part of the lighttpd.conf file is shown below.

```
server.modules += ("mod_fastcgi")
fastcgi.server = (
    "/main.py" => ((
    "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.socket",
    "bin-path" => "/srv/http/main.py",
    "max-procs" => 1,
    "bin-environment" => (
          "REAL_SCRIPT_NAME" => "",
          "POSTGRES_USER" => "postgres",
    ),
    "check-local" => "disable"
  )),
)
fastcgi.debug = 1
```

lighttpd has access to the /tmp folder and when lighttpd is running it creates the /tmp/fastcgi.socket file.

Comment: There's a rogue comma after `"postgres",` and `)),`